# PHP: Rename a file without an ext

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, centos

I have tried to use

`rename("/home/folder1/FILE","/home/folder1/NEW")`

However it does not work, FILE is a file without an ext so how do I make php recognize that?

And yes I have `chmodded` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem. You probably don't have the right to write inside the directory.

Comment: (directed at original post) ^-- True example of **Sticky Keys**.

Comment: Or rather, the right user probably doesn't have the right rights to write in the directory, right?

Comment: fopen requires the right to read the file, rename requires the right to write inside the directory. `chmod 777 /home/folder1` but you should better set the owner of the directory to php

Comment: is php user the owner of the file ? check & chown